# how to assign a value to a variable fetched from java bean over JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am working on JSP and servlets. I need to fetch values from java bean and assign it some other variable over JSP.

Usually I fetch the value in html tags as ${abcd.variable_name}

but this thing can't be used it we want to get some value in <% %>

Comment: What's your use-case for needing to do this?

Comment: @DaveNewton - I need to get String value from bean so that i can further pass it into FusionChart String

Comment: You're writing Java in your JSP?

Comment: @DaveNewton - Yes, It is a small snippet. Just to fetch string and pass it into DOM parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on where the bean is stored. If it is stored in the request scope as a request attribute, just get it back as request attribute:

```
<%
    Bean bean = (Bean) request.getAttribute("bean");
    // ...
%>
```

Or if it's stored in the session scope as a session attribute, just get it back as session attribute:

```
<%
    Bean bean = (Bean) session.getAttribute("bean");
    // ...
%>
```

Or if it's stored in the application scope as an application attribute, just get it back as application attribute:

```
<%
    Bean bean = (Bean) application.getAttribute("bean");
    // ...
%>
```

However, you're doing the desired job at the [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) place. It has to be done in a normal Java class like a servlet or at least the action class of the MVC framework you're using, if any.

Comment: Masterreportrequest.java is my servlet and Buildingmasterservice.java is my bean class. In servlet this is how i forward variables - request.setAttribute("buildmast", building_master);  so should i call bean class or servlet in <jsp:useBean id="bean1" class="" scope="request" /> and then further how to write my  Bean bean = (Bean) request.getAttribute("bean");

Comment: You don't need `<jsp:useBean>` at all when you're already using servlets. It would only duplicate and confuse everything. You have stored it as a request attribute with name `"buildmast"` in the servlet, so you should also get it as such: `BuildingMaster buildingMaster = (BuildingMaster) request.getAttribute("buildmast");`.

Comment: Actually i had tried this but it show an error in this line saying "BuildingMaster cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: You've to import it by `<%@page import="com.example.BuildingMaster" %>` in top of JSP. By the way, why not just doing the preparing job in the servlet? You keep fiddling with ugly and old fashioned *scriptlets* while you're already using a servlet which can just prepare exactly the data you need for the JSP.